SQL Server not producing same result as Excel
I have the following PMT function:
create function dbo.PMT
(
    @rate float,
    @periods numeric(20,7),
    @principal numeric(20,2)
)

returns numeric (38,9)

as
begin

    declare @pmt numeric (38,9)

    declare @WK_periods float,
        @WK_principal float,
        @wk_One float,
        @WK_power float

    select  @WK_periods = @periods,
        @WK_principal = @principal,
        @WK_One = 1

    select  @pmt =
        round(
        ( @WK_principal * (@rate*power(@WK_One+@rate,@WK_periods)))
        / (power(@WK_One+@rate,@WK_periods)-@WK_One)
        ,9)

    return @pmt

end
go

and called with the following parameters:
SELECT dbo.PMT(0.006313333, 251.1762480, 1814647.77)

the result is 14425.46 while excel is producing 14334.96. Though, I noticed that excel user added 2 extra parameters, which make it different from SQL result. So, in excel, the PMT function is called as =PMT(0.006313333, 251.1762480, 1814647.77, 0, 1). I could add those 2 parameters but don't know what to do with them in the function as I don't understand their implementation.
I need help to make SQL server produce same result as Excel.

You need to understand the logic of what the function is trying to accomplish if you want our help in accomplishing it.

Aside... float is an approximate number type. You would get different results again if you were to use decimal(38,9) everywhere.

Alternatively you could post (Somewhere not sure where) asking for an explanation on how the PMT function works - but here is not the place for that.

maybe refer to PMT function

Thanks Squirrel for the link, AlwaysLearning, thanks for your comment. I had to change @periods int to @periods numeric(20,7) to get the result, almost close to that of Excel.
@DaleK, it's an inherited task & the original developer is no longer working there & from my findings, it used to work well before he left.
Hence, the reason I came for help here.

14425.46 = 14334.96 * (1 + 0.006313333), so the difference is one period of interest.  One of the extra parameters in Excel selects whether payments are applied at the start of each period or at the end. This would account for the difference. Compare =PMT(0.006313333, 251.1762480, 1814647.77, 0, 1) with =PMT(0.006313333, 251.1762480, 1814647.77, 0, 0).

But we can't help if you don't know how it is supposed to work.

@AlwaysLearning, TN
=PMT(0.006313333, 251.176248, 1814647.77, 0, 1) produces -14334.96  where as =PMT(0.006313333, 251.176248, 1814647.77, 0, 0) or =PMT(0.006313333, 251.176248, 1814647.77) produces -14425.46

@TN, thanks for the insight. I have just gotten the 14334.96 by using 14425.46 * (1 - 0.006313333)
And thanks to everyone who made comments on this. Your comments guided me.

This answer contains a javascript version of the PMT() function that includes the begin/end-of-period payment option. You should be able to adapt that logic. (I expect somewhere out there is a SQL Server implementation matching EXCEL, but I didn't find it after a limited search.) I did find this PDF containing various reference formulas.

And regarding the data type used for the calculations, I believe float is fine, if not preferred for performance. The result need only be converted back to decimal at the end (and only if you prefer that as your return type). Typically the calculated payment would be rounded up to the nearest cent (or whatever currency precision is being used), and a FV() calculation performed using that rounded payment to determine the residual adjustment needed for the final payment.

@TN you might as well write an answer rather than a bunch of massive comments

Corrected: As for the sign difference, I believe EXCEL uses a standard sign convention that I follows the formula pv * (1 + rate)^nper + (pmt / rate) * ((1 + rate)^nper - 1) + fv = 0, where what you add to the account (present-value and payments-in) are positive, and what you take out (payments-out and future-value payout) are negative, such that the final sum is zero. In its simplest form with no payments and no interest, pv + fv = 0, which might not be intuitive, but that is just the way the general formula works. (This is the form for payments applied at the end of each period.)

Apache POI has a Java version of Excel's PMT function. See FinanceLib.java.
Translating this into Transact SQL should be
CREATE function [dbo].[PMT]
(
    @rate float,
    @periods numeric(20,7),
    @principal numeric(20,2),
    @future numeric(20,2),
    @type bit
)

returns numeric (38,9)

as
begin

    declare @pmt numeric (38,9)

    declare @WK_periods float,
        @WK_principal float,
        @WK_future float,
        @WK_One float

    select  @WK_periods = @periods,
        @WK_principal = @principal,
        @WK_future = @future,
        @WK_One = 1

    if @rate=0

        select  @pmt = round(
            -@WK_one * (@WK_future + @WK_principal) / @WK_periods
        , 9)

    else
        select  @pmt = round(
            ( @WK_future + @WK_principal * power(@WK_One + @rate, @WK_periods) ) * @rate
            / 
            ( iif(@type=1, @rate + @WK_One, @WK_One) * (@WK_One - power(@WK_One + @rate, @WK_periods) ))
        , 9)

    return @pmt

end
GO

Then
SELECT dbo.PMT(0.006313333, 251.1762480, 1814647.77, 0, 0)

results in -14425.460840909
SELECT dbo.PMT(0.006313333, 251.1762480, 1814647.77, 0, 1)

results in -14334.959468244
In general, any programming project that attempts to implement Excel functions requires implementations of the functions in the project's programming language. If such projects are open source then one can have a look into the source code to get how the implementations where done. Then one can try to adopt this into the needed programming language.
